# I cant read my cookie out in google chrome but I can in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am setting a cookie to hide a cookie notice on a my website.

This works fine in all other browsers but Google Chrome(and Opera to it seems) (not even tested in IE yet)

Here is my code that reads out the cookies and makes the decision whether to run the show function or do nothing.

This function is called up on page load

```
 checkCookie = function() {
        var myCookieSet = getCookie("useofcookies");
        if (myCookieSet != "closed"){
            alert('cookie is not set and = '+  myCookieSet);
            // run the show info bar function
            init();     
        }else {
            alert('cookie HAS BEEN set and = '+  myCookieSet);
        }
};
```

I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.
Full js file can be found here:

[Cookie Notice - Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kuMHRCqV)

Any clues as to why would this is happening in Chrome alone would be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried clearing your cache and cookies? IE a 'clean browser'?

The code looks fine and when I use your code it seems to work for me. Even in IE 8/9

Comment: Yes, I found that out this morning, but thanks. Since you put this and it did work I gave you the mark for correct answer. :-)